# Angular expression parse error trying to filter an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter

Say, I have an array `[null, 'foo', 'bar']`, and I want to filter it to remove null values and join to a string like so:

`[null, 'foo', 'bar'].filter(function(el) { return el !== null; }).join(', ')`

If I write this piece of code in a controller and `console.log();` it, everything works fine, no errors. But if I write an angular expression with curly braces in my view like:

```
<p>{{ [null, 'foo', 'bar'].filter(function(el) { return el !== null; }).join(', ') }}</p>
```

angular spits out a parse error:

```
Syntax Error: Token '{' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 42 of the expression [[null, 'foo', 'bar'].filter(function(el) { return el !== null; }).join(', ')] starting at [{ return el !== null; }).join(', ')].
```

In my project, this controller has many variables affecting this final string, and they change in many functions. Of course, I could write a function to write the final string into a controller variable, say, `vm.finalString`, like so:

```
vm.updateFinalString = function() {
    vm.finalString = [vm.var1, vm.var2, ...].filter(function(el) { return el !== null; }).join(', ');
}
```

and inject this function into every function that changes these variables after they change, and echo the `vm.finalString` in curly braces in my view, but it seems like a lot of code duplicating. Is it a "feature" of angular or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: You can't have such logic in template, and this is good: templates must be clean and simple.

Comment: @dfsq, okay, I got it, angular documentation for expression forbids function declaration. Seems like I have to write this logic in a controller with a lot of code duplicates, but hey, there should be some programming routine :)

Comment: You don't have to duplicate code, there are plenty of ways to avoid this. Services, mixins, and even controller inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own custom filter and here is the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) on  how to do that.